# render json using jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, templates

I have below Json output

```
{ "IDsInThisList":"28184,28181,28180,28178","RowsReturned":"4","List" :[{"ContentID":28184,"ArticleType":"News","Headline":"Mobile Bytes","Article":"<p>HTC CFO Chialin Chang expects the manufacturer&rsquo;s fortunes to change for the better going in to 2014.</p>"}]}
```

I need to get "Headline" out and display it using jquery template, i normally uses {{:Headline}} but for somereason its not working, possibly because its inside "List", how to i render "Headline" out?

Comment: json not directly populate the html your have to use any javascript template engine: eg :JADE

Answer (score 3):

Parse the string using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) then access using `a.List[0].Headline`

```
var a=JSON.parse('{ "IDsInThisList":"28184,28181,28180,28178","RowsReturned":"4","List" :[{"ContentID":28184,"ArticleType":"News","Headline":"Mobile Bytes","Article":"<p>HTC CFO Chialin Chang expects the manufacturer&rsquo;s fortunes to change for the better going in to 2014.</p>"}]}');

console.log(a.List[0].Headline);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/UuSVY/)

Comment: But how to display using Jquery template?

Comment: what you mean by Jquery template?